# ssl connection for RJDBC

Tags: r, rjdbc

My company is instituting an ssl requirement soon for database connections.

I previously connected to our Vertica database via DBI and RJDBC packages. I have tried adding an `sslmode='require'` parameter to my connection. But adding this parameter has no effect. I can still connect to the database but the connection is not ssl.

Can anyone advise on how to enable ssl connection for DBI? In PyCharm I merely had to set ssl to true in the driver properties.

```
DBI::dbConnect(
    drv = RJDBC::JDBC(
        driverClass = driver_class,
        classPath = class_path
    ),
    url = url,
    UID = user_id,
    PWD = password,
    sslmode = 'require'
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A different ssl parameter was required. I am having connection success with the function below that uses `ssl = 'true'`

```
    DBI::dbConnect(
        drv = RJDBC::JDBC(
            driverClass = driver_class,
            classPath = class_path
        ),
        url = url,
        UID = user_id,
        PWD = password,
        ssl = 'true'
    )
```